# PHP with DOM Xpath - Remove childNode and arrange string

Tags: php, domxpath

I have this html structure:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div>
        <div>
          <section>
            <div>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr></tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                      <i></i>
                      <div class="first-div class-one">
                        <div class="second-div"> soft </div>
                        130 cm / 15cm
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr></tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I have this XPath code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHtmlFile('http://www.whatever.com');
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );

$nodelist = $xpath->query( '/html/body/section/div[2]/section/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div' );
foreach ( $nodelist as $node ) {
    $result = $node->nodeValue."\n";
}
```

This gets me 'soft 130 cm / 15cm' as a result.

But I want to know how to get only '15', so I need:

**1. To know how to get rid of the childNode->nodeValue**

**2. Once I have '130 cm / 15cm', to know how to get only '15' as the nodeValue of a variable in PHP.**

Can you guys help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `nodeValue` is just a text string. DOM's job is done once you have that string - you'll need to use standard PHP string operations (e.g. substr) to manipulate it, then stuff the modified string back into the DOM.

Comment: Yep, that's why the title says 'php with dom xpath'. I know what to do if I only want to get '130', but not if I want only '15'. Besides, the first thing I need is the child div's value 'soft' to be removed, which is a dom xpath thing. Also the substrings surrounding '15' may change in the real html code I'm working with.

Comment: and I'm telling you that you have your `130 cm /15cm` string, and now have to use standard php string operations to further break that down. which means that technically your question has NOTHING to do with dom. dom did its job, now you need OTHER tools.

Comment: I don't have '130 cm /15cm' yet. I have 'soft 130 cm / 15cm'. Please, go read the original question.

Comment: @MarcB, I think you haven't read that there's a child div whose value is 'soft'. That was the first part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text within a tag is also a node (a child), more particularly a `DOMText`.
By looking at the children of that `div`, you can find the `DOMText` and get its `nodeValue`. An example below:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body><p>bah</p>Test</body></html>");
echo $doc->saveHTML();

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( '/html/body' );
foreach ( $nodelist as $node ) {
    if ($node->childNodes)
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
                    if($child instanceof DOMText)
                            echo $child->nodeValue."\n"; // should output "Test".
            }
}
```

Your second point can easily be done with regular expressions:

```
$string = "130 cm / 15cm";

$matches = array();
preg_match('|/ ([0-9]+) ?cm$|', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

**Full Solution:**

```
<?php

$strhtml = '
<html>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div>
        <div>
          <section>
            <div>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr></tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                      <i></i>
                      <div class="first-div class-one">
                        <div class="second-div"> soft </div>
                        130 cm / 15cm
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr></tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($strhtml);
echo $doc->saveHTML();

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( '/html/body/section/div/div/section/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div' );
foreach ( $nodelist as $node ) {
    if ($node->childNodes)
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
            if($child instanceof DOMText && trim($child->nodeValue) != "")
            {
                echo 'Raw: '.trim($child->nodeValue)."\n";
                $matches = array();
                preg_match('|/ ([0-9]+) ?cm$|', trim($child->nodeValue), $matches);
                echo 'Value: '.$matches[1]."\n";
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Weboide, thanks for your help. Your basic example works fine as expected. But this is the output I get with your code: https://eval.in/511219 The 'Null' result comes from the var_dump I added at the end. If I delete the var_dump, it outputs nothing.

Comment: Your xpath was wrong with the first `div[2]`, see my edits, I added a full solution. Don't forget to vote and select my answer if this solved your problem, Thanks!